# How to use different secrets for each environment in Expo EAS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

How can we differentiate secrets for each environment (development, preview and production) in Expo when running eas build command to build or publish the expo app?

From the secrets screen in the expo console, it seems to be global for the application:

[image]

So, no matter which the environment is when you're trying to build, it seems that the secret is going to be the same. For example, if I need the value of an API_KEY env to be different in the preview environment from the production environment, how can I accomplish that using expo secrets?

Answer (score 1):

1. Prefix profile specific (development, production etc.) env vars with the profile name e.g. `DEVELOPMENT_API_KEY`
2. Strip the profile prefix depending on the build profile - as shown by the code below

```
/* app.config.ts */

// Set profile specific environment variables
const profilePrefix = `${process.env.EAS_BUILD_PROFILE?.toUpperCase()}_`;
Object.entries(process.env)
  .filter(([key]) => key.startsWith(profilePrefix))
  .forEach(([key, value]) => (process.env[key.slice(profilePrefix.length)] = value));
```